# Corresponding Vector to TRUE/FALSE Vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I have two vectors

```
> filename
[1] "10021978_1909-07-21_ed-1_seq-4"  "10021978_1910-01-19_ed-1_seq-31"
[3] "10021978_1910-01-19_ed-1_seq-31" "10021978_1910-01-19_ed-1_seq-31"
[5] "10021978_1910-01-19_ed-1_seq-31" "10021978_1911-06-07_ed-1_seq-12"
[7] "10021978_1911-07-05_ed-1_seq-11" "10021978_1911-07-12_ed-1_seq-11"
[9] "10021978_1911-07-12_ed-1_seq-11" "10021978_1911-09-27_ed-1_seq-4"
```

AND

```
> dups = duplicated(filename)
> dups
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

I am dealing with exporting files but not overwriting files with duplicate file names. I have a few that are duplicates in this set of 10. What I need to do is make those filenames unique.

How can I create a new vector that would have nothing wherever the vector `dups` is `FALSE`, and then nonzero wherever `TRUE`? The tricky thing is that I need it to begin incrementing starting with 2 when there is a series of `TRUE` next to each other then reset when there is a `FALSE`. The vector I need for this set would be:

`ans = c("", "", 2, 3, 4, "", "", "", 2, "")`

so that I can append it to the filenames to deal with duplicates. The final filename vector I need would be:

```
[1] "10021978_1909-07-21_ed-1_seq-4"  "10021978_1910-01-19_ed-1_seq-31"
[3] "10021978_1910-01-19_ed-1_seq-31-2" "10021978_1910-01-19_ed-1_seq-31-3"
[5] "10021978_1910-01-19_ed-1_seq-31-4" "10021978_1911-06-07_ed-1_seq-12"
[7] "10021978_1911-07-05_ed-1_seq-11" "10021978_1911-07-12_ed-1_seq-11"
[9] "10021978_1911-07-12_ed-1_seq-11-2" "10021978_1911-09-27_ed-1_seq-4"
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why not just `make.unique(filename)`?

Comment: Beautiful. That function is going to change my life. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make.unique` should be good enough, but if you need the numbering to start at 2, perhaps it is easier to use `ave`.

Here is an example of both so you can see the difference between the two approaches:

```
a <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "d", "e")
make.unique(a, sep = "-")
# [1] "a"   "a-1" "a-2" "b"   "c"   "d"   "b-1" "d-1" "e"  

dups <- ave(a, a, FUN = seq_along)
a[duplicated(a)] <- paste(a[duplicated(a)], dups[duplicated(a)], sep = "-")
a
# [1] "a"   "a-2" "a-3" "b"   "c"   "d"   "b-2" "d-2" "e"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking for. Bottom line was I needed unique file names, but this takes it a step further and lines up with the duplicate convention on my OS. Perfect.